# How to add a client side element to a server side page within Next.js 13 app folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

My ultimate goal is to have my most viewed articles displayed based on the count from my database. Currently it works every time I rebuild, because it is server side. I would like to fetch the view count data on the client side for the UI to automatically display the correct articles.

This is my page.tsx file within the app directory in Next.js 13:

```
// Prisma
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma"

// Sanity
import { client } from "@/lib/sanity-client"
import { groq } from "next-sanity"

// Components
import { Container } from "@/components/Container"
import SimpleIntro from "@/components/Intros/SimpleIntro"
import SimpleIntroCentred from "@/components/Intros/SimpleIntroCentred"
import FeaturedList from "@/components/Posts/Lists/FeaturedList"
import List from "@/components/Posts/Lists/List"

async function getArticles() {
  const query = groq`
    *[_type == "article"] {
        ...,
        author->,
        categories[]->} 
    `

  if (!query) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data")
  }

  const article = await client.fetch(query)

  return article
}

async function getViewCount() {
  const views = await prisma.view.findMany({
    where: { contentType: "article" },
  })

  return views
}

export default async function ArticlePage() {
  const articles = await getArticles()
  const views = await getViewCount()

  const mostViewedArticles = views
    .sort((a: any, b: any) => Number(b.count) - Number(a.count))
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map((view: any) => {
      const article = articles.find(
        (article: any) => article.slug.current === view.slug,
      )
      return article
    })

  return (
    <Container className="grid gap-20 lg:gap-32 mb-40">
      <div className="grid gap-10">
        <SimpleIntroCentred
          title="Let's read"
          description="Read my most popular articles and perhaps discovery a new upcoming interest of yours."
          customClass="animate-fade-in-top"
        />

        <SimpleIntro
          title="Most popular"
          description="Read my most popular articles and perhaps discovery a new upcoming interest of yours."
          customClass="animate-fade-in-bottom"
        />

        <FeaturedList
          data={mostViewedArticles}
          contentType="article"
          customClass="animate-fade-in-bottom"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="grid gap-10 animate-fade-in-bottom">
        <SimpleIntro
          title="All articles"
          description="Find something that you find interesting and be creative."
        />

        <List data={articles} contentType="article" />
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

This is the part I would like to get on the client side:

```
async function getViewCount() {
  const views = await prisma.view.findMany({
    where: { contentType: "article" },
  })

  return views
}
```

How can I accomplish that with the app directory structure?